# ASP.NET WebForms whitelabel with themes

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We currently have an ASP.NET WebForms app built for a client and we want to build another whitelabeled version for another client. The problem is: we were thinking of using themes, but besides some labels and images we also have resource files which need to be different, some notification/admin emails and some URLs.

Is themes a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. App_Themes would be a good idea to implement your requirement.

You can define number of themes in your App_Themes folder.

[image]

Images ruquired by each theme and the css rules can be placed inside each theme.

[image]

Finally, You can call your themes in the aspx file.

```html
<link href="../App_Themes/Blue/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: but how to handle admin emails set up in web.configs or resources? For example for resources_EN-US.resx we would have different resources for the whitelabeled app: resources-wl_EN-US.resx. Themes can't handle this from what I know